# Prevent jwplayer video full screen on double click

Tags: javascript, html, html5-video, jwplayer

I have a modal dialog which contains a jwplayer video element. I do not want a user to be able to double click on the video element and go to full screen.

Is there a way to prevent this from happening?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [HTML5 - Prevent Fullscreen Mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44743559/html5-prevent-fullscreen-mode)

Comment: Added information on type of video player. The link refers to a youtube player.

Comment: Have you found any solution?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
const player = document.getElementById('player');
player.allowFullscreen = false;
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.